# Unable to insert row with non-nullable foreign key in sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have 3 tables.

Emoji, EmojiPost, User.

Useful information about schema is as follows:

```
EmojiPost.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'user' });
EmojiPost.belongsTo(Emoji, {foreignKey: 'emoji_type'});
User.hasMany(EmojiPost, {foreignKey: 'user', onDelete: 'cascade'});
```

When i have defined association like this, I am able to do the following to insert a EmojiPost into the database:

```
var data = {
    // some fields
    user: 1,
    emoji_type: 1
}

EmojiPost.create(data);
```

this works perfectly. However, I want the foreign keys to be non-nullable, so I change the association definition as follows:

```
EmojiPost.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: {field: 'user', allowNull: false} });
EmojiPost.belongsTo(Emoji, {foreignKey: {field: 'emoji_type', allowNull: false}});
User.hasMany(EmojiPost, {foreignKey: 'user', onDelete: 'cascade'});
```

And after that, even though data contains both emoji_type and user values, yet I receive non-null constraint violation for both of them.

I also tried the following for insertion:

```
var emoji = await Emoji.findByPk(1);
var user = await User.findByPk(1);
var emoji_post = EmojiPost.build(data); // here data does not contain user and emoji_type
emoji_post.setEmoji(emoji);
emoji_post.setUser(user);
emoji_post.save();
```

This throws the error that setEmoji and setUser functions are not defined. I have been stuck on this for the entire day, any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. The primary key of Emoji is emoji_id (because I have underscored: true in the definition). Even though I have specified the foreign key to be emoji_type in the definition, the name of the column in the actual table in postgres is emoji_type, but sequelize expects me to pass this value as emojiId for some reasons. If I do that, then it works, but I still don't know why it expects emojiId.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Here is an example using `"sequelize": "^5.21.3"`:

`index.ts`:

```js
import { Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
class User extends Model {}
class EmojiPost extends Model {
  public user!: number;
  public emoji_type!: number;
}
class Emoji extends Model {}

User.init({}, { sequelize, modelName: 'User' });
EmojiPost.init({}, { sequelize, modelName: 'EmojiPost' });
Emoji.init(
  {
    emoji_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: 'Emoji' },
);

// EmojiPost.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'user' });
// EmojiPost.belongsTo(Emoji, { foreignKey: 'emoji_type' });

EmojiPost.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: { name: 'user', allowNull: false } });
EmojiPost.belongsTo(Emoji, { foreignKey: { name: 'emoji_type', allowNull: false } });

User.hasMany(EmojiPost, { foreignKey: 'user', onDelete: 'cascade' });

(async function test() {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    await User.create();
    await Emoji.create();
    const data = { user: 1, emoji_type: 1 };
    await EmojiPost.create(data);

    const data2 = { user: null, emoji_type: null };
    await EmojiPost.create(data2);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await sequelize.close();
  }
})();
```

If you don't set `allowNull: false` to `foreignKey` option. Sequelize will throw an error when you try to save `data2` due to violating the `NOT NULL` FK constraint. The error is below as expected:

```sh
name: 'SequelizeValidationError',
  errors:
   [ ValidationErrorItem {
       message: 'EmojiPost.user cannot be null',
       type: 'notNull Violation',
       path: 'user',
       value: null,
       origin: 'CORE',
       instance: [EmojiPost],
       validatorKey: 'is_null',
       validatorName: null,
       validatorArgs: [] },
     ValidationErrorItem {
       message: 'EmojiPost.emoji_type cannot be null',
       type: 'notNull Violation',
       path: 'emoji_type',
       value: null,
       origin: 'CORE',
       instance: [EmojiPost],
       validatorKey: 'is_null',
       validatorName: null,
       validatorArgs: [] } ]
```

The data records in the database:

```sh
node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "Emoji";
 emoji_id
----------
        1
(1 row)

node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "User";
 id
----
  1
(1 row)

node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "EmojiPost";
 id | user | emoji_type
----+------+------------
  1 |    1 |          1
(1 row)
```

As you can see, `data2` is not saved into the database as expected.

`db.ts`:

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'postgres',
  host: envVars.POSTGRES_HOST,
  username: envVars.POSTGRES_USER,
  password: envVars.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
  database: envVars.POSTGRES_DB,
  port: Number.parseInt(envVars.POSTGRES_PORT, 10),
  define: {
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false,
  },
});
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/node-sequelize-examples/tree/master/src/examples/stackoverflow/60127106